# How do i remove debug messages that mongo outputs

Tags: java, mongodb

So when I connect to my mongo server/DB via java, I get messages that I've connected successfully, and along with it useless info. How do I remove this irrelevant info?
[image]

All the text in red

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the MongoDB documentation on logging (which you should read!), the Mongo driver will look for [SLF4J](https://www.slf4j.org/) on the classpath at runtime. If it is available, it will use it. Otherwise, it will fall back to `java.util.logging` aka JUL.

In your case, it would appear that *no* SLF4J was found, and thus, you will need to configure JUL if you want these INFO level messages to not appear. You have a couple of options to do this.

The quickest and dirtiest way (**but not recommended**, as it would potentially impact every Java program utilizing JUL on your machine) is to find `logging.properties` in your JRE's lib directory: <jre install dir>/lib. There is a line in there that will look like this:

```
.level=INFO
```

Change the INFO level to WARNING or SEVERE

```
.level=WARNING
# or
.level=SEVERE
```

The **better** way would be to make a copy of the aforementioned `logging.properties` file (found in <jre install dir>/lib) somewhere in your project and make the same changes. When running your program, simply add the following system property:

```
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=<path to logging.properties>
```

Comment: i just used         LogManager.getLogManager().reset();
and it works

Comment: Sure, but if you ever actually want to *view* the log statements that Mongo outputs, that will not work.